# Getting FileSystemNotFoundException from ZipFileSystemProvider when creating a path to a resource

Tags: java, maven

I have a Maven project and inside a method I want to create a path for a directory in my resources folder. This is done like this:

```
try {
    final URI uri = getClass().getResource("/my-folder").toURI();
    Path myFolderPath = Paths.get(uri);
} catch (final URISyntaxException e) {
    ...
}
```

The generated `URI` looks like `jar:file:/C:/path/to/my/project.jar!/my-folder`.

The stacktrace is as following:

```
Exception in thread "pool-4-thread-1" java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException
    at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.getFileSystem(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:171)
    at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.getPath(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:157)
    at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:143)
```

The `URI` seems to be valid. The part before `!` points to the generated jar-file and the part after it to `my-folder` in the root of the archive. I have used this instructions before to create paths to my resources. Why am I getting an exception now?

Comment: Is the Zip file in a format readable by the ZipFileSystemProvider?

Comment: The folder exists in the root. And the jar-file is generated by Maven, thus it should be readable.

Comment: If you already have the `URL`, you don't need a `File` or `Path` just to read its contents. You can just call `URL.openStream()` and read from the `InputStream` that method returns. If you actually *must* have a `File` or `Path` object, then you'll need the `FileSystem` fixes mentioned below. But most things don't really need a file and can handle `InputStream` or `Reader` interfaces, so I'd suggest going down the `URL.openStream()` route first if possible.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You need to create the file system before you can access the path within the zip like

```
final URI uri = getClass().getResource("/my-folder").toURI();
Map<String, String> env = new HashMap<>(); 
env.put("create", "true");
FileSystem zipfs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, env);
Path myFolderPath = Paths.get(uri);
```

This is not done automatically.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html

Comment: I am using the same technique to access a jar file. But the problem that I am facing is that whenever there is a space char in the path, I get the same error. It works fine otherwise

Comment: Yes, spaces and characters beyond the ASCII range in file paths cause problems with the nio. Also when files in the jar/zip have these characters. But this is a different problem, You may find help here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37936627/uri-to-file-in-zip-incorrect-if-path-contains-spaces

Answer (score 14):

If you intend to read the resource file, you can directly use `getClass.getResourceAsStream`. This will set up the file system implictly.
The function returns `null` if your resource could not be found, otherwise you directly have an input stream to parse your resource.

Answer (score 13):

Expanding on @Uwe Allner 's excellent answer, a failsafe method to use is

```
private FileSystem initFileSystem(URI uri) throws IOException
{
    try
    {
        return FileSystems.getFileSystem(uri);
    }
    catch( FileSystemNotFoundException e )
    {
        Map<String, String> env = new HashMap<>();
        env.put("create", "true");
        return FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, env);
    }
}
```

Calling this with the URI you are about to load will ensure the filesystem is in working condition. 
I always call `FileSystem.close()` after using it:

```
FileSystem zipfs = initFileSystem(fileURI);
filePath = Paths.get(fileURI);
// Do whatever you need and then close the filesystem
zipfs.close();
```

Comment: Careful, a `ZipFileSystem` can be closed, but a `WindowsFileSystem` will complain.

Answer (score 10):

In addition to @Uwe Allner and @mvreijn:

Be careful with the `URI`. Sometimes the `URI` has a wrong format (e.g. `"file:/path/..."` and correct one would be `"file:///path/..."`) and you cant get a proper `FileSystem`.
In this case it helps that the `URI` is created from the `Path`'s `toUri()` method.

In my case I modified `initFileSystem` method a little bit and used in non exceptional cases the `FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, Collections.emptyMap())`. In exceptional case the `FileSystems.getDefault()` is used.

In my case it was also necessary to catch the `IllegalArgumentException` to handle the case with `Path component should be '/'`. On windows and linux the exception is caught but the `FileSystems.getDefault()` works. On osx no exception happens and the `newFileSystem` is created:

```
private FileSystem initFileSystem(URI uri) throws IOException {
    try {
        return FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, Collections.emptyMap());
    }catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
        return FileSystems.getDefault();
    }
}
```