# java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException when getting file from resources folder

Tags: java, nio

I am getting this error on the following code (note that this does not happen on my local machine, only on my build server):

```
Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(getClass().getResource("/elasticsearch/segmentsIndex.json").toURI()), Charset.defaultCharset());
```

And the exception:

```
Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException: null
at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.getFileSystem(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:171)
at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.getPath(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:157)
at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:143)
```

I tried to fix it by following this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25032716/getting-filesystemnotfoundexception-from-zipfilesystemprovider-when-creating-a-p); my code now looks like this:

```
URI segmentsIndexURI = getClass().getResource("/elasticsearch/segmentsIndex.json").toURI();
Map<String, String> env = new HashMap<>(); 
env.put("create", "true");
FileSystem zipfs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(segmentsIndexURI, env); //exception here
Path segmentsIndexPath = Paths.get(segmentsIndexURI);
```

I am getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path component should be '/'
at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.checkUri(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:77)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newFileSystem(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:86)
at java.nio.file.FileSystems.newFileSystem(FileSystems.java:326)
at java.nio.file.FileSystems.newFileSystem(FileSystems.java:276)
```

Nothing seems to work.
How am I supposed to build the path to the file?

Comment: did you note that the exception in question title is not the same as the exception in the post ? please clarify.

Comment: You're passing the URI of a **file** as a new **file system**? I do not know how this can make sense.

Comment: note that the exception mentioned in the description is the one i am getting after following the solution. the first code snippet is the one throwing the exception in the title... i can include the original exception as well if you like

Comment: did you open your jar or directory deployment to see if your file is present or not in it? and at the correct place?

Comment: works fine on my local machine, so i assume it is something to do with the environment, or else the path would not work on local run as wlel

Comment: @Gleeb The reason it is working on your local machine is probably that you are running it in an IDE and the resource is actualy a file in that mode. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22605666/java-access-files-in-jar-causes-java-nio-file-filesystemnotfoundexception

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Don't try to access a resource like a file. Just grab the InputStream and read the data from there:

```
byte[] data;
try (InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/elasticsearch/segmentsIndex.json")) {
    data = in.readAllBytes​(); // usable in Java 9+
    // data = IOUtils.toByteArray(in); // uses Apache commons IO library
}
```

This example uses the IOUtils class from Apache commons-io library.

If you are targeting Java 9+ you can alternatively use `data = in.readAllBytes​();`.

Comment: I had to add `getClass().getClassLoader()`

Answer (score 6):

Generally, it is not correct to assume that every resource is a file. Instead, you should obtain the URL/InputStream for that resource and read the bytes from there. Guava can help:

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/elasticsearch/segmentsIndex.json");
String content = Resources.toString(url, charset);
```

Another possible solution, with the InputStream and apache commons: [Convert InputStream to byte array in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264709/convert-inputstream-to-byte-array-in-java) .

From a byte[], simply use the String constructor to obtain the content as a string.

Answer (score 3):

You should get the resource through an `InputStream` and not a `File`, but there is no need for external libraries.

All you need is a couple of lines of code:

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/elasticsearch/segmentsIndex.json");
java.util.Scanner scanner = new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
String json = scanner.hasNext() ? scanner.next() : "";
```

You can learn more about that method at https://stackoverflow.com/a/5445161/968244

Answer (score 3):

If you use Spring, inject resources. Be it a file, or folder, or even multiple files, there are chances, you can do it via injection. Warning: DO NOT use `File` and `Files.walk` with the injected resources, otherwise you'll get `FileSystemNotFoundException` when running as JAR.

This example demonstrates the injection of multiple images located in `static/img` folder.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

@Service
public class StackoverflowService {

    @Value("classpath:static/img/*")
    private Resource[] resources;
    private List<String> filenames;

    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
        final Predicate<String> isJPG = path -> path.endsWith(".jpg");
        final Predicate<String> isPNG = path -> path.endsWith(".png");

        // iterate resources, filter by type and get filenames
        filenames = Arrays.stream(resources)
                .map(Resource::getFilename)
                .filter(isJPG.or(isPNG))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, didn't know about that injection of `Resources[]`, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `getResourceAsStream(…)` instead of `getResource(…)`. There are a number of methods to read all bytes into a byte array, e.g. Apache Commons has a utility method to do just that.