# Exception handling with NIO in java

Tags: java, nio

The following code throws **java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException** when run. What might be the reason?

```
Path p = Paths.get(new URI("file://e:/temp/records"));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException when getting file from resources folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29746667/java-nio-file-filesystemnotfoundexception-when-getting-file-from-resources-folde)

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrectly specified the uri, it is missing a `/`. Try running these in JSHELL to see that the correct value is `"file:///e:/temp/records"`:

```
Paths.get(new URI("file://e:/temp/records"))
==> \\e\temp\records      [ INCORRECT PATH]

Paths.get("e:\\temp\\records").toUri()
==> file:///e:/temp/records

Paths.get(new URI("file:///e:/temp/records"))
==> e:\temp\records     [ CORRECT PATH TO E: ]
```